# Why can i not append an element to a struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

struct StructName{
    var name: String?
    var specs: [Spec]?

    init(specs: [Spec]? = nil, name: String? = nil) {
        self.specs = specs
        self.name = name
    }

}

struct Spec{
    var name: String
    var title: String
    var content: String
    var display: Bool
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var structNames: [StructName] = []
    var specs = [Spec]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            specs.append(Spec(name: "Name_1", title: "Title_1", content: "Content_1", display: false))
            structNames.append(StructName(name: "Name_3"))
            structNames.append(StructName(name: "Name_4"))
            structNames.append(StructName(name: "Name_1"))

            append()
            print(structNames)
    }


    func append(){
        for i in specs{
            let index = structNames.index { (structName) -> Bool in
                structName.name == i.name
            }
            print(structNames[index!].name)

            structNames[index!].specs?.append(Spec(name: "a", title: "a", content: "a", display: false))
        }
    }


}
```

Why does this not work?

```
        structNames[index!].specs?.append(Spec(name: "a", title: "a", content: "a", display: false))
```

It should print this:

> [test.Utility(utility_name: Optional("Name_3"), specs: nil), test.Utility(utility_name: Optional("Name_4"), specs: nil), test.Utility(utility_name: Optional("Name_1"), specs: "SPEC I APPENDED")]

As you may understand, I want to append the given Spec to a specific index.

Comment: Because the `specs` of the `structNames` instance is `nil`.

Comment: Are you saying that I should change my default initialiser to something else?

Comment: Yes just give it a default value `var specs: [Spec] = []`

Comment: Thanks that worked, just answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the `specs` property of each `StructName` to anything other than `nil`. So when you reference `structNames[index!].specs`, `specs` is `nil` and the optional chaining skips the call to `append`.

One solution is to initialize `specs` to an empty array instead of `nil`.

```
struct StructName{
    var name: String?
    var specs: [Spec]

    init(specs: [Spec] = [], name: String? = nil) {
        self.specs = specs
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

FYI - do you really want an optional `name`?

Comment: I need it to be nil, this was just an example taken from a project with a nested json response.

Comment: But in the comments below your question you stated that this worked.

Comment: Yeah by giving a default initialiser with an empty array. I was talking commenting about the "name" with you.